# is it available save the user session on web server?

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

This code is only for a user.
I'm looking for the way to make this for multiple user.

Please, give me some tips.

To run the batch job, I know that some variables (is_authorized, requestToken and accessToken) should be removed. I tried to use spring-social-tumblr(on github)but it was not easy to use ConnectionRepository. so I tried to use signpost.

After signing with signpost, how could I set the user access token for multi-user?

Is it right to use OAuthConsumer class?

```
@Controller
public class TumblrProfileController {
    private OAuthService service;
    private Token requestToken; //should be removed for multiuser
    private Token accessToken; // same above

    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info";

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Inject
    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private boolean is_authorized = false;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/tumblr/webrequest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(OAuthConsumer user, Model model) {



        final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info";
        service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(TumblrApi.class).apiKey("clientKey")                    .apiSecret("secretKey").callback("http://localhost:8080/pen/tumblr/login").build();

        log.info("Fetching the Request Token...");

        // Obtain the Request Token
        requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
        log.info("Now go and authorize Scribe here:");
        String redirectUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
        log.info(redirectUrl);
        return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tumblr/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@RequestParam(required = false) final String oauth_verifier) {
        Verifier verifier = new Verifier(oauth_verifier);

        // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
        log.info("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
        accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
        log.info("Got the Access Token!");
        log.info("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken + " )");
        // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
        log.info("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
        log.info("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
        log.info(response.getBody());
        log.info("Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with Scribe! :)");
        run();
        is_authorized = true;
        return "tumblr/feed";
    }
    public void run() {

        try {
            if(! is_authorized ) return;

            OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
            service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
            Response response = request.send();
            log.info("[2nd Call ]Got it! Lets see what we found...");
            log.info(response.getBody());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Dear editor. Please do not modify the 'Source Code'. It could makes another question.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've not used Spring Social Tumblr (it's a community-led project), the process shouldn't be much (or any) different than using Spring Social with Facebook or Twitter.

Note that in this code, you're doing too much work. You're going to the trouble of redirecting to Tumblr for authorization and then handling the redirect to exchange the request token and verifier for an access token. Certainly, those things must be done, but with Spring Social there's absolutely no reason why *you* have to do those things. That's what ConnectController is for. ConnectController handles all of that, creates and persists the connection, and (generally speaking) you never have to muck about with OAuth directly. And, it has no problem working with multiple users.

May I recommend that you look at the Spring Social Showcase example at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase to see how it's done? That example connects with Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn, but there's really no reason why it couldn't connect to Tumblr in the same fashion. For a much simpler approach that leverages Spring Boot and automatic configuration, you might also have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot. (Note, however, that Spring Boot doesn't have autoconfig for Tumblr, so there'd still be some manual config required.)

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried to save the session for batch job. There are two problems. One is, the social tumblr does not match with spring-social-showcase-xml. even I make jsp view files and interceptor same with facebook. it just returnes "social_authorization_error"

Comment: Thanks to your work on social-framework, I'm trying to use the Connection Contoller with original source. I'm gonna post self-solution here  after completing this job.